# CURL File with post parameter

Tags: curl, facebook

How to make a request for uploading a file to facebook using graph api in curl

I am making this request but getting Error:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/photos  -F "source=@me.jpg"  -d "message=Me"  -v
```

ERR:

Only One Http Request can be Selected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `-F` and `-d` together, since they use different content types, and you need `multipart/form-data`. So try with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/photos -F "source=@me.jpg" -F "message=Me" -v
```

From `man curl`:

> -F/--form
>
> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type **multipart/form-data** according to RFC2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.