# How to POST file contents using cURL?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, curl

I want to do an `HTTP POST` of the ***contents*** (as a string) of a local file located at `path/to/my-file.txt` to a URL endpoint at `http://example.com/`.

For example, I might want to do the following:

1. Extract the contents of the file `my-file.txt` as a string.
2. URL encode the string.
3. Store the encoded string as a variable named `foo`.

Then do something like this:

```
curl -d "data=foo" http://example.com/
```

(I don't actually need the `foo` variable. It's just a convenient way to describe my question.)

What are the commands I would need to execute this? Do I need to write a shell script? If so, how might it look?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143915/test-file-upload-using-http-put-method

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to the last section of `-d` in `man curl`:

If you start the data with the letter `@`, the rest  should  be  a file  name  to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting  data  from  a  file  named `foobar` would thus be done with `--data @foobar`. When `--data` is told to read  from  a  file  like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out.

That is you don't have to do anything fancy just prepend your filename with a `@`.

Comment: And if you want some useful shell escaping (eg. to use jq to preprocess some JSON, try:
```curl ... -d @<(jq '{"schema": . | tostring }' myschema.avsc')```
Use-case: wrap a JSON document into a string of another JSON document to pass it to a REST API. (Confluent Schema Registry)

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you're uploading binary files, you should use `--data-binary`.

Comment: how can we post data from a url?

Comment: PLEASE How can I stop stripping line endings from the file input? I need it because of elasticsearch bulk format needs to ended with new line.

Comment: @Čamo See the comment of Ahmet

Comment: I found it already.

Answer (score 39):

As mentioned in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408904/send-post-request-with-data-specified-in-file-via-curl) if you want the file uploaded without any changes (curl defaults to stripping carriage-return/line-feed characters) then you may want to use the `--data-binary` option:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @path/to/my-file.txt http://example.com/
```

Comment: But I need to send application/json but with line endings

Comment: I need it because of Elasticsearch _bulk api and the solution is to send header Content-Type: application/x-ndjson

Answer (score 25):

To be explicitly clear, the accepted answer suggests:

```
curl -d "data=@path/to/my-file.txt" http://example.com/
```

[The manual reference is here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d).

[Also see this SE answer](https://superuser.com/a/543773/471181) and [this one also for multi-parts](https://superuser.com/a/442989/471181).

Comment: Not really.  The way you state it can be confusing, and people might not know what you mean.  The original question wanted to have `data=foo` sent to the server.  The file called my-file.txt would contain only `data=foo`.  Then the curl syntax would be `curl -X POST -d @path/to/my-file.txt http://example.com`.  Your syntax is a bit non-standard and confusing.

Comment: Does not upload the file for me.